# How to update a pixel value across 3 channels in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

The goal I'm trying to achieve is to update a pixel in all 3 RGB channels of a Tensor. For example,

```
t1 = tf.zeros([4, 4, 3], tf.int32)
```

`t1` is a tensor with 4x4 as (x,y) of the pixel and 3 channels. I use `tf.where` to find the index of the highest value in another tensor of same shape like

```
t2 = tf.random.uniform([4, 4, 3], maxval=10, dtype=tf.int32)
tf.where(tf.math.reduce_max(t2), 1, t1)
```

But this only changes the value of the single index which had the highest value in `t2`.
What I'm looking for is to update that (x,y) in all 3 channels.

For instance if `t2` looked like
Channel 1 -> [[1 2],[3,4]]
Channel 2 -> [[5 6],[7,8]]
Channel 2 -> [[1 0],[0,0]]
The max value is 8 which is the (1,1) index within the channel.

I would like then `t1` to look like
Channel 1 -> [[0 0],[0,1]]
Channel 2 -> [[0 0],[0,1]]
Channel 2 -> [[0 0],[0,1]]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: _But this only changes the value of the single index_... as far as I can see, you are not doing any side effect, maybe you missed a line where you are actually using the index from `tf.where`

Answer (score 0):

This will do it , I think. You need to reduce down to a 2-D tensor and then
tile it across the channel dimension.

```py
# Sample tensor for demo purposes with integers 0-7, the max will be in t2[1,1,1]
# Channel is dimension 2
t2 = tf.reshape([i for i in range(8)],(2,2,2))
print(f"{t2=}")

mask3 = tf.cast(t2 == tf.reduce_max(t2), tf.int32)     # 3-D integer mask, identifies the cell with max value
mask2 = tf.reduce_max(mask3, axis=2, keepdims=True)    # Reduce across channel dimension, find pixel with max value
t1 = tf.tile(mask2, (1, 1, t2.shape[2]))              # Tile to get 1 in target pixel across all channels
print(f"\n{t1=}")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we get the (partial) indices to update as

```
idx = tf.where(t2 == tf.reduce_max(t2))[..., :-1]
```

or if there can be multiple positions with max value and you only want to use the first one, then

```
idx = tf.where(t2 == tf.reduce_max(t2))[:1, ..., :-1]
```

Having the partial indices, we can update `t1` using [`tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update).

```
t1 = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(t1, idx, tf.ones((idx.shape[0],t1.shape[-1]), tf.int32))
```

This is applicable to any tensor with two or more dimensions, with the last dimension being the "channel" dimension.